# Angular-cli or Webpack

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

I used `angular-cli` in our one project. Now, we came to know about `webpack`. As per my research, `webpack` is faster than `angular-cli` and it also removes unused code. I don't know about drawbacks.
I just want to know that which one is better to use in all ways like website speed, less code etc.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

the latest version of `angular-cli` uses `webpack` see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#webpack-update

Answer (score 3):

Yes , correct. 
https://ajsblackbelt.wordpress.com/2016/09/24/why-should-you-use-angular-cli/

Snippet of this site content.

> ...The angular team went the extra mile and created anguar-cli – a very powerful tool that goes way beyond the simple bundler or generator.
>
> It has Webpack under the hood, already pre-configured ..

Comment: @bvnio, Can i use angular-cli for complex front end application?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is a module bundler and task runner.

- It manages your 3rd party app dependencies
- It allows you to do “code splitting”
- Helps minify your files
- Compile SASS to CSS etc

Angular CLI is a command line interface that bundles some of the techniques mentioned above. Under the hood it uses Webpack. It is easy to create an application that works out of the box.